# How do I resolve a UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning with Jest in node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, testing, jestjs

My tests are passing correctly but I keep receiving a UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning. Any ideas on how to resolve this please?
I've tried many solution but none seem to work.

```
node:32535) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: expect(received).toMatchObject(expected)

Matcher error: received value must be a non-null object

Received has value: undefined (node:32535) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:32535) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This my test file:

```
jest.mock("./http");
const { fetchAllUsersData } = require("./http");

test("Data returned from server should be a list of users ", async () => {
  fetchAllUsersData()
    .catch((errorMessage) => expect(errorMessage).toThrowError(Error))
    .then((usersRetrieved) => {
      let users = usersRetrieved[0];
      let userModel = {
        id: 1,
        first_name: "Peggy",
        last_name: "Poppins",
        email: "mpoppins0@squidoo.com",
        ip_address: "192.54.212.191",
        latitude: 34.003135,
        longitude: -117.7228641222,
      };

      expect(users).toMatchObject(userModel);
    });
});
```

This is my file inside the **mock** folder:

```
      const fetchAllUsersData = () => {
        return Promise.resolve({
          data: [
            {
              id: 1,
              first_name: "Merry",
              last_name: "Poppins",
              email: "mpoppins0@squidoo.com",
              ip_address: "192.54.212.191",
              latitude: 34.003135,
              longitude: -117.7228641,
            },
            {
              id: 15,
              first_name: "George",
              last_name: "Foreman",
              email: "gforeman@clear.com",
              ip_address: "12.564.124.521",
              latitude: 23.592254,
              longitude: 125.454227,
            },
          ],
        });
      };

      exports.fetchAllUsersData = fetchAllUsersData;
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this error is that a promise wasn't chained to be returned from the test. A floating promise is an antipattern. `async..await` allows to achieve this with a bit less discipline than it's required for raw promises. It usually doesn't make sense to use raw promises together with `async`. Also, it doesn't make sense to test both successful and failed requests in the same test, an expected response is supposed to be predetermined.

`expect(errorMessage).toThrowError(Error)` will only work if `errorMessage` is a function that synchronously throws an error. It won't work as expected if `fetchAllUsersData` rejects with `errorMessage` object.

It likely should be in one test:

```
test("...", async () => {
  const usersRetrieved = await fetchAllUsersData();
  ...
  expect(users).toMatchObject(userModel);
});
```

In another test:

```
test("...", async () => {
  await expect(fetchAllUsersData()).rejects.toThrowError(Error);
});
```

Also, tests don't serve a good purpose if you test your own test code supplied in `__mock__`. They should test production code.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your suggestions. Your solution throws an error

Comment: Error: expect(received).toMatchObject(expected)

Matcher error: received value must be a non-null object

Received has value: undefined

Comment: that is for the first test you suggested

Comment: It shouldn't throw an error if the assertion is correct. This part was addressed in another answer that was deleted, it should be `usersRetrieved.data[0]` because `usersRetrieved` is not an array and `usersRetrieved[0] === undefined`, and it's 'user' this way, not 'users'. As I mentioned, you don't need to test your own test code except for educational purposes.

Comment: You're welcome. A real-world test will likely be similar but you'll need to mock the thing that actually does the request (`fetch`, DB, etc) instead of the thing that uses it (fetchAllUsersData) in the test that is dedicated to fetchAllUsersData unit.